# Spring data jpa @Query метод не достает значения из БД при нескольких where

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-jpa

Когда выбираю объекты с запросом типа

```
@Query(value = "select * from ingredient where type=?1", nativeQuery = true)
List<Ingredient> findByType(String type);
```

все работает нормально, но если

```
@Query(value = "select * from ingredient where type=?1 and type=?2", nativeQuery = true)
List<Ingredient> findByType(String type, String type2);
```

не находит ни один объект

Kак это исправить?

Comment: Может быть условие должно быть не "и", а "или"? В этом виде тип должен принадлежать и к типу 1 и к типу 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Query(value = "select * from ingredient where type=?1 or type=?2", nativeQuery = true)
List<Ingredient> findByType(String type, String type2);
```

Выберет из базы все объекты с типом 1 или типом 2

Answer (score 0):

Я понял свою ошибку, просто, нужно несколько раз вызвать метод на разные типы, а не пытаться вместить вызов разных объектов в один запрос. Осознание пришло только сейчас...